# Time Aware Recommender System would work for my data set?

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I have implicit feed back data.

```
Customer Data: <CustomerID> <Product Bought> <Date of Purchase>
                C1             P1                01-11-2008
                C1             P2                01-01-2009
                C1             P3                01-01-2020
                C2             P1                01-01-2021
```

I am building a recommender system. I have used co-occurrence matrix to build the recommender system. I have used Graph lab to do it. I also used Jaccard similarity measure for it.

Now my objective is to recommend products which customer likely to buy in next 6 months. For C2, I should recommend product P2 and not P3. How to handle this problem? I did learn about CARS (context-aware recommender systems) esp. [Fast FM](https://github.com/ibayer/fastFM). It looks like it did not serve me well. Please help me how to handle problem. Item-item similarity is not doing well for me.

Comment: What are you running the similarity against?  Your sample data has no customer identification but you mention "customer" in the question.  Did you mean `<Customer ID>` instead of `<Company ID>`?

Comment: My bad. Fixed now.